# how to read,store and fetch data paragraph wise in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

I am building a website in php where i have to store the data entered in textbox to database. As i have to store and retrieve data in indian languages i have changed the collation to utf8. Now i could write and fetch data in any language but it cannot be fetched paragraph wise.

```
$obj = new dboperation();

$query="SELECT t.t_no, t.title, t.date, u.u_name 
            FROM user u, travellogue t, home as h
            where t.u_no=u.u_no and t.t_no=h.t_no and h.t_no=t.t_no and h.slot=2";

$result=$obj->selectdata($query);

$f=$obj->fetch($result);

echo "<h1 class=entry-title>".$f[1]."</h1>
      <div class=meta-info>
          <div class=td-post-author-name>
            By <a href='http://demo.tagdiv.com/newsmag_travel/author/admin/'>".$f[3]."</a> -
          </div>
          <span class=td-post-date><time class='entry-date updated td-module-date' datetime=''>
            ".$f[2]."</time>
          </span>
          <div class=td-post-views><i class=td-icon-views>
            </i><span class=td-nr-views-1031>159</span>
          </div>
          <div class=td-post-comments>
            <a href='http://demo.tagdiv.com/newsmag_travel/2015/09/02/td-post-dont-make-these-rookie-travel-mistakes/#respond'>
              <i class=td-icon-comments></i>0
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>";
```

this is the code i have used to fetch and display data. it display the data correctly but not aligned in paragraph wise

Comment: There is no `<textarea>` in that HTML. It's unclear what you mean by "_cannot be fetched paragraph wise_". Try providing sample output of what you expected and sample output of what you actually got that you didn't expect to make this clear if you cannot express the problem clearly in words.

Comment: Deinfe "paragraph wise".

Comment: Do you have `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in the `<form ...>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

try nl2br($f[1]). this will replace newline characters you put in the textbox with html ’br ’ tags

Comment: And put two linefeeds in the 'textarea' to indicate a paragraph.